# Asymptotic Variance of MLE Exponential

Tags: exponential-distribution, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Suppose we have a random sample $(X_{1},.....,X_{n})$, where $X_{i}$ follows an Exponential Distribution with parameter $\lambda$, hence:

$F(x) = 1 - exp(-\lambda x)$

$\mathbb{E}(X_{i}) = \dfrac{1}{\lambda}$

$ Var(X_{i}) =\dfrac{1}{\lambda^{2}}$

I know that the MLE estimator $\hat{\lambda} = \dfrac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}}$, asymptotically follows a normal distribution, but I'm interested in his variance.
So, since $\sqrt n (\hat{\lambda} - \lambda)\stackrel{D}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^{2}) $

I was thinking about dealing with:

\begin{align}
\sigma^{2} &= Var\left[\sqrt n (\hat{\lambda} - \lambda)\right]\\
&= n Var (\hat{\lambda})\\
&= n Var \left[ \dfrac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}} \right] \\
&= n^{3} Var \left[ \dfrac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}}\right]
\end{align}

But I don't know how to proceed from here. I think the sum of exponentials follows a gamma with parameters $(n,\lambda)$, and that $\dfrac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}}$ then follows an inverse gamma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes  you are almost there.

You can calculate the variance of $\hat{\lambda}=\frac{n}{Y}$ remembering that

$$Y=\Sigma_i X_i \sim \text{Inverse Gamma}$$

and thus you immediately solve the problem as its variance is a known parameter

...but you can also solve the problem using the integration, and calculating

$$\mathbb{V}\Bigg[\frac{1}{Y}\Bigg]=\mathbb{E}\Bigg[\frac{1}{Y^2}\Bigg]-\mathbb{E}^2\Bigg[\frac{1}{Y}\Bigg]$$

It is not difficult:

$$\mathbb{E}\Bigg[\frac{1}{Y}\Bigg]=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{y}\frac{\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)}y^{n-1}e^{-\lambda y}dy=\frac{\lambda}{n-1}\underbrace{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n-1)}y^{(n-1)-1}e^{-\lambda y}dy}_{=1}=\frac{\lambda}{n-1}$$

and similarly for the second simple moment

**Anyway this is not the asymptotic variance** but it is the exact variance. To calculate the asymptotic variance you can use [Delta Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method)

---

After simple calculations you will find that the asymptotic variance is $\frac{\lambda^2}{n}$ while the exact one is $\lambda^2\frac{n^2}{(n-1)^2(n-2)}$

Comment: Perfect, I got the math, but now I have another question. How come does the asymptotic variance depend on n? According to what we have from your explanation, we would get:

$\sqrt n (\hat{\lambda} - \lambda)\stackrel{D}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^{2})$

where:

$\sigma^{2} = \lambda^{2} \dfrac{n^{2}}{(n-1)^{2} (n-2)}$

Comment: And also, I found alternatives explanations. It seems that we can also use the Cramer Rao lower bound. How does that fit here?

Comment: @S.Cow . Yes, CR lower bound is the same of delta Method. Try,  as an example, to find asymtotic and exact variance of $\hat{\frac{1}{\lambda}}$

Comment: So, when I do the asymptotic variance via the delta method, I get that the variance is $\lambda^{2}$. I'm a little confused, because it is not the same as the asymptotic variance $\dfrac{\lambda^{2}}{n}$

Comment: @S.Cow : that is not possible. Delta method and CR inequality have the same formula...just a different name . the denominator is the Fischer information...

Answer (score 1):

Following the discussion with @tommik, I am still struggling with something:

Since $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean and given the properties of $(X_{1},....X_{n})$ in the problem set, the Central Limit Theorem tell us that:

$\sqrt{n}\left(\bar{X} - \dfrac{1}{\lambda}\right) \stackrel{D}{\rightarrow}  \mathcal{N}\left(0, \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{2}}\right)$

We can apply the Delta Method:

Consider the function $h(x) = x^{-1}$, where $h'(x)= -x^{-2}$, therefore:

$\sqrt{n}\left(h(\bar{X}) - h(\frac{1}{\lambda}) \right) \stackrel{D}{\rightarrow}  \mathcal{N}\left(0, \overbrace{\left[h'(\frac{1}{\lambda})\right]^{2} \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{2}}}^{\sigma^{2}}\right)$

$\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\lambda} - \lambda\right) \stackrel{D}{\rightarrow}  \mathcal{N}\left(0, \left[h'(\frac{1}{\lambda})\right]^{2} \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{2}}\right)$

Where notice that the argument inside of the function $h'()$ is $\dfrac{1}{\lambda} = \lambda^{-1}$.

Let's find out what the variance $\sigma^{2}$ is:

\begin{align*}
\sigma^{2} &= \left[h'\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)\right]^{2} \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{2}}\\
&= \left[ - \left(\dfrac{1}{\lambda}\right)^{-2} \right]^{2} \dfrac{1}{\lambda^{2}}\\
&= \dfrac{\lambda^{4}}{\lambda^{2}}\\
&= \lambda^{2}\\
\end{align*}

So, I don't know how to conciliate the comments and answers above.